# How to effectively communicate the license of database content?

Tags: licensing, license-notice, creative-commons

I'm working on a project make some New Zealand government data available to the public under the Creative Commons license. The access to the data will be directly to a **PostgreSQL database** (read-only, of course). I'm unsure what would be an appropriate mechanism to ensure that anyone accessing the database could be made aware of its license.

One obvious mechanism would be to include a notice next to the connection parameters mentioning the license, possibly like [this](https://creativecommons.org/choose/non-web-popup?license_code=by&jurisdiction=&version=4.0&lang=en):

> This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License. To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/ or send a letter to Creative Commons, PO Box 1866, Mountain View, CA 94042, USA.

Of course, not everyone connecting to the database might see this, but maybe that's just the same problem as people distributing a repository without the license file?

Comment: On a practical note, if you give randoms direct access to your SQL server you can expect it to be permanently DoS'd by malicious queries.

Comment: It won't be accessible without a password, and will probably be gatekept with an API key. Please refrain from lecturing without any evidence.